# Seemingly impossible NullPointerException inside dispatchTouchEvent

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I have an Android app that crashes on some devices with a NullPointerException inside my implementation of dispatchTouchEvent. I've never actually seen the crash happen on any of my devices, but it happens many times a day in the field, because I see crashes both in my own analytics and in the Android Developer console. The problem is that I am having a hard time figuring out how this crash can possibly be happening. Here's the relevant code (I marked the place in the code where the NullPointerException is thrown by "CRASH HERE ->"):

```
if (…)
{
    ...
}
else if (event != null)
{
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        motionStartX = event.getX();
        motionStartY = event.getY();
    }
    else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
    {
        ...
        if (...)
        {
            ...
        }
        else if         (event != null && event.getPointerCount() > 0 &&
 /*** CRASH HERE -> ***/(Math.abs(motionStartX - event.getX()) > 5 ||
                         Math.abs(motionStartY - event.getY()) > 5))
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

From my understanding, the only way a NullPointerException could be thrown there is if `event` is `null`, however, on the line just above it I added some paranoid checks for `event` being `null` and even that the event has pointers. Still, I'm getting crashes. I feel like I'm missing something. Does anyone have any insight into this?

Comment: As I said in the question, I can't reproduce this issue on my devices, so I don't see how my logcat output would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

0) I think the problem is you are not handling exceptions.

1) these two (motionStartX , motionStartY) should declare above the crash code and  must initialize (set),

2) Check that you are not processing wrong data type for example you are not using string as integer.

3) use try Catch statement to handle exception, if this is exception not bug

4) use Log.d("values on fun", "motionStartX = " + motionStartX  " , motionStartY= " + motionStartY + " , event.getX() = " + event.getX()  " , event.getY() = " + event.getY());
Tp pring values,If values are there then no null points,

```
else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
{
    try{ 
        Log.d("values on function", "motionStartX = " + motionStartX  " , motionStartY= " + motionStartY + " , event.getX() = " + event.getX()  " , event.getY() = " + event.getY());
        ...
        if (...){
            ...
        }
        else if         (event != null && event.getPointerCount() > 0 &&
        /*** CRASH HERE -> ***/(Math.abs(motionStartX - event.getX()) > 5 ||
                     Math.abs(motionStartY - event.getY()) > 5)){
                       ...
        }catch(Exception e){
          //Handle exceptions here, if they are exceptions not bugs in your code
       }
  }
```

Comment: Amir, thank you for your response.  
  
0). Of course I could put this into a try-catch block and solve the problem that way. However, I'd like to understand why a NullPointerException is thrown.  
  
1). motionStartX and motionStartY are initialized above the code I quoted. The code wouldn't compile otherwise.  
  
2). I'm not sure how processing string as integer would cause a NullPointerException. Can you be more specific? What string might I be using as integer and in what context? Since Java is typed, that kind of stuff is generally hard to get past the compiler.  
  
3). Same as 0.

Comment: 4). I've tried logging values similarly to what you suggested. First of all, as I mentioned in the question, I can't reproduce this on my devices, so Log.d wouldn't help. Second, I did add analytics around this to see what's going on, but it revealed that nothing that's being used here is null.

Comment: If you are unable to find issue on ur device and emulators. Can you find out what kind of device or specific device is producing this issue (Any response from customer/cunsumer),It can be hardware problem or configuration problem of some specific device